# The default expression for the query parameter contains an error

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a dataset referencing a proc.  That proc takes in a @UserName
In my parameters of my dataset, I have specified a new param called @UserName and for its default value the expression =User!UserID but I still get this error when the report tires to render:

The default value expression for the query parameter @UserName contains an error [BC30654] 'Return' statement in a function, Get, or Operator must return a value

The only thing I can think of is that instead of modifying the existing datasource I had defined in the report, I removed and added a new datasource.  I hope that doesn't matter as long as there is a valid data source for the report to go on that has those fields...I just switched this report to reference a copy of our current database for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the report parameter is not being passed to the stored procedure.
In the Dataset Properties, click on the Parameters tab and check that the stored proc parameter @Username is correctly mapped to the Report parameter @Username.